# How to resize a matrix in beamer

Tags: matrices, scaling

Currently I am having problem in resizing the matrix. The following is the code:

```
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{XXX}

$$\small\begin{pmatrix}

I_{\frac{k}{2} \times \frac{k}{2}} & 0_{\frac{k}{2} \times \frac{k}{2}} & 1_{\frac{k}{2}\times 1} & E_{\frac{k}{2} \times (\frac{l}{2}-1)} & 0_{\frac{k}{2}\times 1} & 0_{\frac{k}{2} \times (\frac{l}{2} -1)} & 1_{\frac{k}{2} \times (f_2 - \frac{l}{2})} & D_{\frac{k}{2} \times (f_1 - \frac{l}{2})} & A\\

0_{\frac{k}{2} \times \frac{k}{2}} & I_{\frac{k}{2} \times \frac{k}{2}} & 0_{\frac{k}{2}\times 1} & 0_{\frac{k}{2}\times (\frac{l}{2} -1)} & 1_{\frac{k}{2}\times 1} & F_{\frac{k}{2} \times (\frac{l}{2} -1)}& C_{\frac{k}{2} \times (f_2 - \frac{l}{2})} & 1_{\frac{k}{2} \times (f_1 - \frac{l}{2})} & B
\end{pmatrix}$$

\end{frame}
```

The following is the image produced:

[image]

Clearly it is missing the last column containing $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Try to use `\noindent$...$` instead of double dollar.

Comment: It's not working. I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only tricky bit is that \resizebox puts you back into text style.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{XXX}

\[\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{$\displaystyle\begin{pmatrix}

I_{\frac{k}{2} \times \frac{k}{2}} & 0_{\frac{k}{2} \times \frac{k}{2}} & 1_{\frac{k}{2}\times 1} & E_{\frac{k}{2} \times (\frac{l}{2}-1)} & 0_{\frac{k}{2}\times 1} & 0_{\frac{k}{2} \times (\frac{l}{2} -1)} & 1_{\frac{k}{2} \times (f_2 - \frac{l}{2})} & D_{\frac{k}{2} \times (f_1 - \frac{l}{2})} & A\\

0_{\frac{k}{2} \times \frac{k}{2}} & I_{\frac{k}{2} \times \frac{k}{2}} & 0_{\frac{k}{2}\times 1} & 0_{\frac{k}{2}\times (\frac{l}{2} -1)} & 1_{\frac{k}{2}\times 1} & F_{\frac{k}{2} \times (\frac{l}{2} -1)}& C_{\frac{k}{2} \times (f_2 - \frac{l}{2})} & 1_{\frac{k}{2} \times (f_1 - \frac{l}{2})} & B
\end{pmatrix}$}\]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: slide]

Comment: Yup, it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use the `medize` environment, defined in the `nccmath` package: this size is ~80 % of displaystyle:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{XXX}
\[
\begin{medsize}\begin{pmatrix}
I_{\frac{k}{2} × \frac{k}{2}} & 0_{\frac{k}{2} × \frac{k}{2}} & 1_{\frac{k}{2} × 1} & E_{\frac{k}{2} × (\frac{l}{2}-1)} & 0_{\frac{k}{2} × 1} & 0_{\frac{k}{2} × (\frac{l}{2} -1)} & 1_{\frac{k}{2} × (f_2 - \frac{l}{2})} & D_{\frac{k}{2} × (f_1 - \frac{l}{2})} & A\\

0_{\frac{k}{2} × \frac{k}{2}} & I_{\frac{k}{2} × \frac{k}{2}} & 0_{\frac{k}{2} × 1} & 0_{\frac{k}{2} × (\frac{l}{2} -1)} & 1_{\frac{k}{2} × 1} & F_{\frac{k}{2} × (\frac{l}{2} -1)}& C_{\frac{k}{2} × (f_2 - \frac{l}{2})} & 1_{\frac{k}{2} × (f_1 - \frac{l}{2})} & B
\end{pmatrix} \end{medsize}\]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]